# Read from buffered reader by limiting the amount of data being read

Tags: java, escaping

I see the below code in my application to read from buffered reader by limiting the amount of data being read.

```
public static String readBuffer(Reader reader, int limit) throws IOException 
{           
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < limit; i++) {
        int c = reader.read();
            if (c == -1) {
                return ((sb.length() > 0) ? sb.toString() : null);
            }
        if (((char) c == '\n') || ((char) c == '\r')) {
            break;
    }
        sb.append((char) c);
}
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Can someone please explain to me what these lines in the code indicate? Why do we need it?

```
if (((char) c == '\n') || ((char) c == '\r')) {
            break;
    }
```

Comment: It's break line or end line character

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They mean what they say: If `c` is a newline (`\n`) or carriage return (`\r`) then break out of the loop. (A list of escape sequences in Java can be found [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/characters.html), or if you prefer something more official, [JLS section 3.10.6](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.6).)

On a higher level; it means this method will process data until either a) a line-ending is hit, or b) the limit is reached (`i < limit` condition in loop), whichever happens first.

As for *why* you need it: That's because presumably, one of the design requirements for that method was to have it stop at a line-ending, and that `if` statement is the way that requirement was implemented.

Comment: I like your answer very much. Can you please explain this more clearly? - On a higher level; it means this method will process data until either a) a line-ending is hit, or b) the limit is reached (i < limit condition in loop), whichever happens first.

Comment: @rickygrimes I'm not sure how to explain it more clearly. Trace through the logic in your head. The `for` loop will continue as long as `i < limit` - that means it will stop once it has processed `limit` characters. At the same time, that `if ... break` will cause the loop to end early if a `\r` or `\n` is hit. So basically, it will happily process `limit` characters, but if it runs into a newline, it will stop right away no matter what. Does that make more sense? Note there's another condition in there too: If `c == -1` that means the end-of-file was hit, and that also stops the loop early.

Answer (score 2):

```
\n - New Line
\r - Return (Enter)
\n \r \f \t \v     Newline, carriage return, form feed, tab, vertical tab
```

Refer [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/characters.html) and [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.6)

Comment: You might want to link to http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/characters.html or http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.6 instead; the docs you linked to are for regular expressions, and most of what is described there doesn't apply to string/character literals.